# How to make auto_fit columns for GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I use RecyclerView to display Cards.
How can I make columns fit display, because

```
layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getBaseContext(), int);
```

can set only defined number of columns.
As I know there is auto_fit in GridView, but I dont know where should I use it.

**cards_layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="cards main container">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/moccasin"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:tag="image_tag"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<PersonData> peopleDataSet;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewName;
        TextView textViewEmail;
        ImageView imageViewIcon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            this.textViewEmail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
            this.imageViewIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }


    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<PersonData> people) {
        this.peopleDataSet = people;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cards_layout, parent, false);


        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        TextView textViewName = holder.textViewName;
        final TextView textViewEmail = holder.textViewEmail;
        ImageView imageView = holder.imageViewIcon;

        textViewName.setText(peopleDataSet.get(listPosition).getName());
        textViewEmail.setText(peopleDataSet.get(listPosition).getEmail());
        imageView.setImageResource(peopleDataSet.get(listPosition).getImage());

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return peopleDataSet.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-autofit-grid.html .

Comment: @chiuki
exuse me, can you explain how to use your AutofitRecyclerView?
I cant understand how to use it in my MainActivity

Comment: Same question with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575731/gridlayoutmanager-how-to-auto-fit-columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridLayoutManager - how to auto fit columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575731/gridlayoutmanager-how-to-auto-fit-columns)