# RecyclerView Gridlayout Items Fill Their Parents

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have recyclerview like below:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_months"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and I set a grid layout manager for it:

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
```

I want to divide `recylerview` width between these 3 items equally.

This is my item parent:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="96dp">
....
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**How can I divide recylcerview parent between these items equally?**

I want my view look like below: 3 items have equall size and they fill their parent width

[image]

Comment: What's the problem you have faced?

Comment: How can I divide recylcerview parent between these items equally?

Comment: Try to set your CardView width to wrap_content.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575731/gridlayoutmanager-how-to-auto-fit-columns & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH Thank you for your comment. Sorry, I think you didn't get my answer. None of the questions you mentioned is mine.

Comment: Am not sure can you add screenshot of your desired behaviour to make clear. My point you want to set your items width equally in recylerview right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179000/discussion-between-mohamed-mohaideen-ah-and-salman).