# Changing number of columns with GridLayoutManager and RecyclerView for Auto Fit Screen

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

I'm using Recyclerview in fragment...
Inside my fragment I'm setting my GridLayout in the following way:

```
myTV.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),3));
```

code says,***Only 3 columns*** for Landscape and Portrait mode.

**But I want to maximum no.of column** for screen fit for when the user rotates the phone/tablet....

Here is my PeopleFragment.java

```
public class PeopleFragment extends Fragment {
    View v;
        List<People> listPeople;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people,container,false);

            listPeople = new ArrayList<>();

            listPeople.add(new People("1-name",R.drawable.image1));
            listPeople.add(new People("2-name",R.drawable.image2));
            listPeople.add(new People("3-name",R.drawable.image3));
            listPeople.add(new People("4-name",R.drawable.image4));
            listPeople.add(new People("5-name",R.drawable.image5));
            listPeople.add(new People("6-name",R.drawable.image6));
            listPeople.add(new People("7-name",R.drawable.image7));

            RecyclerView myTV= (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
            RecyclerViewAdapterPDF myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterPDF(getActivity(),listPeople);
            myTV.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),3));
            myTV.setAdapter(myAdapter);

            return v;
      }
    }
```

fragment_people.java

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I used **android:numColumns="auto_fit"**.
but I's not working....

Could you tell me how to solve this issue?Here is different question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridLayoutManager - how to auto fit columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575731/gridlayoutmanager-how-to-auto-fit-columns)

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH Thank you for link.But I can't clear the answer,where to put ?

Comment: Check my answer will help you..!

Answer (score 4):

[Check this for better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575731/gridlayoutmanager-how-to-auto-fit-columns)

Here you can create one class for return `no of columns` or use methods directly..

Add this method to your fragment class..

```
public int calculateNoOfColumns(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    int noOfColumns = (int) (dpWidth / 180);
    return noOfColumns;
}
```

& change your adapter code to

```
myTV.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),calculateNoOfColumns(getActivity())));
```

Comment: Welcome glad to help happy coding :)