# LinearLayout - line breaks if views do not fit in one line

Tags: android

Is there some way to set up a `LinearLayout` or a `ConstraintLayout` to put as many views in a linear chain and simply start a new row as soon as not all views fit into the current row?

Like following:

```
Item1 - Item2 - Item3 - Item4
Item5 - Item6 - Item7 - Item8
Item9 - Item10
```

Or on a larger screen

```
Item1 - Item2 - Item3 - Item4 - Item5
Item6 - Item7 - Item8 - Item9 - Item10
```

As far as I know `LinearLayout` can't do this at all and `ConstraintLayout` does not support such line breaks inside a chain.

Any other way to get what I want? (Not programmatically calculating available space and putting `LinearLayouts`  inside a parent `LinearLayout` container, I know how to do this - I'm looking for a more beautiful solution).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38472370/8114201

Comment: This weblike behaviour is avilable on flexbox layout https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: I want to avoid a custom view for this. @VolkanSahin45, the RV based solution looks interesting, thanks, I'll check this out. I did not think about an RV for some case...